# Marketing cloud: How to tie Open/Click events with Sent events

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have Sent events which has SendID, SubscriberKey, BatchID, TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID and SubscriberID. And the similar columns are available in Open/Click.

How to map one Sent event to its corresponding Open/Click?

Essentially I want to know on which datetime that particular Sent was Opened and Clicked? Or in another words I want to know the composite key of Open/Click to tie with Sent events/table?

Comment: if you want get the   date and time  for opens  and clicks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main Unique ID that is passed between the Sent, Open and Click Dataviews is the JobID and SubscriberKey.

- JobID represents a sendable job (User Initiated Send or Wizard Immediate/Schedule Send, latest published TSD)
- SubscriberKey equals the unique identification of each subscriber stored inside of SFMC (this is the email address by default)

So basically:

`_Sent (JobID) + _Open (JobID) + _Click (JobID) = All sends, opens and clicks for that job.`

You can then use the SubscriberKey to get down to subscriber level stats inside of the Job.

If you wanted to, you could also use ListID (for a specific list, not limited to job or timeframe).

As to indirect connections, you can push the _Sent DV against the _Job DV and pull only JobIDs that sent a certain email (via EmailName), certain Subject (via EmailSubject), etc.

But keep in mind, the more complex you make the connection, the more complex the SQL - leaving open more possibility of human error and increasing processing speed.  Which will push you closer to the 30 min timeout limitation.

Comment: Hi @Gortonington, what is 30min timeout limitation?

Comment: And there could be an instant when one SubscriberKey may have 2 sent dates for the same JobID and I need to track open/click for each of them seperately. What would I do in that case?

Comment: Timeout limitation: if a query runs for more than 30 minutes it will be aborted = not completed

Comment: Can you let me know where it is mentioned in the documentation?